# Show all apps menu flooded with LSP Modules after upgrade to 20.10

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 20.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 recently and the first thing I noticed after rebooting my computer was that my application menu got flooded with many applications, all of them referring to some terms used in audio(like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXtfq.jpg)) and when I open them I get some sort of audio console with their window titles in German language and the active window name on the top left being `lsp-plugins`

Following are the kind of windows I get when I open these apps: one when I tried booting from the [old kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu3VH.jpg)(5.4.0-52--generic) and another app of the same sort when I'm on the [newer kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R4eo.jpg)(5.8.0-25-generic).

I tried:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall lsp-plugins

sudo apt remove lsp-plugins ; sudo apt autoremove ; sudo apt install lsp-plugins
```

and nothing changed on the app menu, these apps even started fine with no errors even after I did `sudo apt remove lsp-plugins ; sudo apt autoremove`.

When the apps are opened through the terminal using `lsp-plugins-nameofprogram` the output is as follows

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
[WRN] Could not connect to JACK (status=0x00000011)
```

this seems to indicate there's no audio jack connected to my laptop, but I only use a Bluetooth device and I've never plugged an audio jack into my Laptop. Judging from the autocomplete feature in the terminal there seems to be 118 apps of this sort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found an answer for this from a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/g40e3a/unwanted_lsp_plugins_showing_up/fo2y3bi?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) in the [r/linux4noobs](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/) subreddit. The solution is in the comments and is posted by [u/mthqwork](https://www.reddit.com/user/mthqwork/). I'll paste the command that I used here. First do

```
echo "[Desktop Entry] Hidden=true" > /tmp/1
```

then do

```
find /usr -name "*lsp_plug*desktop" 2>/dev/null | cut -f 5 -d '/' | xargs -I {} cp /tmp/1 ~/.local/share/applications/{}
```

The applications will now get hidden which is why I didn't see them in my previous Ubuntu version (20.04).

Comment: This issue is caused because GNOME hasn't conformed to XDG standards and has developed it's own mechanism for publishing desktop applications. Normally these apps are grouped into a single folder on other DE's. Ubuntu has worked-around this by hiding them in the application manager but it didn't happen when I upgraded to 20.10 with the newer packages and that was the reason for this.

I've learnt what caused the problem from the same Reddit post from the comment of user r/sadko4u. His account is suspended and I'm not sure if this is the right reason so I'm leaving this in the comments.

Comment: Nice! Solved the problem on Pop OS 20.10

Comment: The same problem is happening to me in Ubuntu 21.04, but unfortunately this solution doesn't seem to work for it. :(

Answer (score 0):

The best (and I think only safe) way to fix this is to bring up the Menu Editor by typing "edit" after clicking on the menu/start button.

Navigate to "LSP Plugins" and choose to not have it show from the menu.

*You can also choose to have the CALF plugin thingie to not show if you have that but don't use it. Cheers!

Comment: this does not apply the hide setting to all the individual entries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Debian Bullseye. I got the package together with PulseEffects equalizer.

After trying the above answers without results, I tried to find details in Debian. The package seems to be called `lsp-plugins-vst`, but I couldn't remove it (it appeared as not installed). I then tried:

```
sudo apt purge lsp-plugin*
```

This command found a few packages to remove and I got rid of the plugins. Success!