# Applications menu filled with lots of LSP apps after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: upgrade, appmenu, 20.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 on my laptop. I looked in the applications menu and there are pages of apps that have the LSP icon and I can't remove them, even when I run `sudo apt remove lsp-plugins`. How do I get rid of these?

Comment: This answer here might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286239/show-all-apps-menu-flooded-with-lsp-modules-after-upgrade-to-20-10

Answer (score 1):

The best (and I think only safe) way to fix this is to bring up the Menu Editor by typing "edit" after clicking on the menu/start button.

Navigate to **LSP Plugins** and choose to not have it show from the menu.

You can also choose to have the CALF plugin thingie to not show if you have that but don't use it. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

First, run the command `sudo apt remove lsp-plugins` to know which packages were installed but are not needed. Then, run `sudo apt autoremove` to clear them out and you'll be good to go.